# Mysql update from select syntax error

Tags: mysql

***Query***

I'm trying to executing the below query but in my phpmyadmin says

> - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM eest_estimated_total pet INNER JOIN eest_total pt ON pt.OrderNo = pet.Order' at line 1

```
UPDATE eest_estimated_total 
SET pet.Freight = pt.FrieghtCost, pet.CustomDuty = pt.ImportDuty 
FROM eest_estimated_total pet 
INNER JOIN eest_total pt 
ON pt.OrderNo = pet.OrderNo 
WHERE pt.OrderNo = pet.OrderNo
```

So may i know where im doing wrong ?

Comment: looks fine, change `UPDATE eest_estimated_total ` to `UPDATE pet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
UPDATE pipo_estimated_total AS pet
INNER JOIN pipo_total AS pt 
ON pt.OrderNo = pet.OrderNo 
SET pet.Freight = pt.FrieghtCost, pet.CustomDuty = pt.ImportDuty   
WHERE pt.OrderNo = pet.OrderNo
```

Comment: @QuestionUser Sorry, I included a `FROM` clause which is not used in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Run This Query :-

```
UPDATE pipo_estimated_total 
SET pet.Freight = pt.FrieghtCost, pet.CustomDuty = pt.ImportDuty 
FROM pipo_estimated_total AS pet 
INNER JOIN pipo_total pt 
ON pt.OrderNo = pet.OrderNo 
WHERE pt.OrderNo = pet.OrderNo
```

Answer (score 0):

As the answer says: [update-from-select-using-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1,
    Table_A.col2 = Table_B.col2
FROM
    Some_Table Table_A
INNER JOIN
    Other_Table Table_B
ON
    Table_A.id = Table_B.id
WHERE
    Table_A.col3 = 'cool'
```

**Your Answer:**

```
UPDATE pet
SET pet.Freight = pt.FrieghtCost, pet.CustomDuty = pt.ImportDuty 
FROM eest_estimated_total pet 
INNER JOIN eest_total pt 
ON pt.OrderNo = pet.OrderNo 
WHERE pt.OrderNo = pet.OrderNo
```

Comment: This may be valid for Sql Server, but it's not valid for MySQL